# Can I use where instead of from which? I want to migrate this question to English Learner Site

Tags: grammar, american-english, relative-clauses, descriptive-grammar

Imagine something secretly entering your body and controlling your behavior, turning you into one of those zombies from science fiction movies. Does that sound creepy? That's exactly how a parasitic fungus species called the “zombie ant fungus,” inhabiting tropical forests around the world, attacks ant colonies. What happens is that when spores from the fungus land on an ant searching for food in the forest, it infects the ant, hijacks its central nervous system, and controls its brain with a special chemical. The victim doesn't act like an ant but like a zombie: it stops searching for food for its colony, and instead climbs up a tree and holds onto a leaf or a branch, where it is finally killed by the fungus. Soon, a stalk of spores grows out of the back of the ant's head, **from which** more spores can access more ants under the tree, a cruel but very effective way of expanding the fungus' territory.

Q 1. Can I use "where" instead of "from which"?

Q 1-1. If it isn't possible, Why?

Comment: 'Where' _could_ be used here. It has a broadened meaning 'in which place/situation'. However, the spatial sense is probably the default here, and this doesn't fit, so you're far better off with the logical 'from which'.

Comment: I don't see any good reason to favour either ***which*** or ***where*** here - they both seem fine to me, and mean the same thing. But it's worth noting that you still need to include the preposition ***from***, otherwise you'd be significantly changing the meaning.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time :)

Answer (score 1):

> Q 1. Can I use "where" instead of "from which"?

No.

> Q 1-1. If it isn't possible, Why?

From is a preposition of motion or change that indicates an origin: "He came from England" "The heat created water from the ice"

Where is an adverb of place. = at, on, or in which place.

You can say:
"... a stalk of spores grows out of the back of the ant's head, **from where** (or **whence** = from which) more spores can access more ants". Whence (and whither) are adverbs of motion and change.

**NB** whence and wither *(and thence and thither, and hence and hither)* are somewhat formal.

Comment: If this is all there is to the question, it should be close-voted as far too basic. However, a good answer would look at peripheral usages of 'where'.